# Set up a proxy for Simplenote

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, https

At work I have a proxy. When I configure it in Linux everything goes perfectly. But now I'm starting to an app call Simplenote that doesn't have a proxy option, so it's not working. What I would like to do is to configure a local proxy (or something similar) that sends everything to the other proxy, so no matter what all programs work on my PC.